# How to limit results of SQLite per specific group of results?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, select, limit-per-group

I have the following problem at work. I have a large table with different columns and few 100 000s of rows. I'll only post the ones im interested in.

Assume the following data set

Device ID, Feature Id, Feature Status

```
1,        1,        0
1,        2,        0
1,        3,        1
1,        4,        1
1,        5,        1

2,        1,        1
2,        2,        0
2,        3,        0 
2,        4,        1
2,        5,        0

3,        1,        1
3,        2,        1
3,        3,        1
3,        4,        1
3,        5,        1

4,        1,        0
4,        2,        0
4,        3,        1
4,        4,        0
4,        5,        0
```

I need to select rows with Feature Status = 1 but only the first 2 from each Device Id.

The results of the query should be:

```
1,3,1
1,4,1
2,1,1
2,4,1
3,1,1
3,2,1
4,3,1
```

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT brdsurfid,featureidx,FeatStatus FROM Features F1 WHERE FeatStatus = 1 AND
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Features F2 
  WHERE F2.FeatureIdx <= F1.FeatureIdx AND F2.FeatStatus = 1) < 2
  ORDER BY BrdSurfId,FeatureIdx;
```

which I found in another response but it didnt quite work.

I know I need to use a mix of LIMIT or COunt(*) and some nested selects but I can't figure it out. Thanks

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: Because I figured people who know SQL and use MySql could help. Why not? It's a database related question, even it's specific to Sqlite, cross experience might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably not a very efficient way to do this, but I don't think there is a better solution for sqlite (that involves a single query):

```
SELECT *
FROM t t0
WHERE FeatureStatus AND
      (SELECT count(*)
       FROM t t1
       WHERE t0.DeviceID=t1.DeviceID
         AND FeatureStatus
         AND t1.FeatureId<t0.FeatureId
      )<2;
```

I assume that the table is called `t`. The idea is to find all features where the status is 1 and then for each feature to count the previous features with that status for the same product. If that count is more than 2, then reject the row.

Comment: let me try it !. This is what i was trying to do myself.

Comment: it doesnt work. It returns all the rows where FeatStatus = 1. :(

Comment: @AlexandruLucianSusma Are you sure? I just run it again with your sample data and it only returns features 3 and 4 (not 5) for device id 1.

Comment: it works fine you are right ! I misstyped something !! Thank you very much !

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will work with sqlite but for what its worth...

```
 ;with result as
 (
      SELECT
         brdsurfid,
         featureidx,
         FeatStatus ,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY brdsurfid ORDER BY fieldWhatever) AS 'someName1',
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY featureidx ORDER BY fieldWhatever) AS 'someName2',
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FeatStatus ORDER BY fieldWhatever) AS 'someName3'

         FROM
            Features
  )
  SELECT * 
  FROM 
     result
  WHERE 
     FeatStatus = 1 AND
     someName1 <= 2 AND
     someName2 <= 2 AND
     someName3 <= 2
```